# Checking if date is valid in javascript get `RangeError: Invalid time value` testing it

Tags: javascript

I created this function to check if the date is valid or not:

```js
function isValidDate(dateObject){
  if(!dateObject) return;
  
    return new Date(dateObject).toString() !== 'Invalid Date';
}
console.log(isValidDate('not valid time')) // false
```

This function  works good, but trying to test it with jest i get this error: `RangeError: Invalid time value`, i suppose that this happens because the argument is a string and it pass the `if(!dateObject) return;`. 
 Question: How to avoid this error in my case?

Comment: Side note: The better way to test that is `return isNaN(Date.parse(dateObject));` (But separately, `dateObject` is a strange name for a string -- not object -- parameter.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, if i change to `return isNaN(Date.parse(dateObject));` i also get that error. Do you know a solution?

Comment: As I said, it's a side note, not an answer to the problem. No, I don't know the solution, because the code shown will not generate that error. Please include your Jest code, which apparently is the source of the error. But another side note (probably not the problem): `if (!dateObject) return;` should presumably be `if (!dateObject) return false;` The function should return `true` or `false`, not `undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, why changing to `function isValidDate(dateObject){
  if(!dateObject) return;
  
    return isNaN(Date.parse(dateObject))
}
console.log(isValidDate('j')) ` i get `true` but i should get `false` ?

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part -- I left out the `!`. It should be `return !isNaN(Date.parse(dateObject));`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, could you help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708238/moment-tz-setdefault-in-react-js-application