# moment.tz.setDefault() in react js application

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using react js to create my application and moment js. According to moment js documentation i can set the timezone globally using: `moment.tz.setDefault()`. Also they said `Default timezone is shared between all modules:`. 
 Question: It is important where to add `moment.tz.setDefault()` or the file where i want to add this does not matter because the configs anyway will be shared over the entire application?

Comment: Where you put it is largely up to you, but I'd do it in the main entry module of my application.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, could you help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70737950/setting-date-and-timezone-is-not-working-in-reactjs