# Setting date and timezone is not working in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a ReactJs project where also i use jest for testing. To display the time according UK timezone, i created this function:

```js
 const getDateTZ = dt => {
  const d = new Date(dt)
  const o = {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    timeZone: 'Europe/London'
  }
  return d.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', o)
}
console.log(getDateTZ(new Date()))
```

This function work fine and running it i get the right time.
To test this function with jest i add this:

```js
test('It should return time', () => {
  const today = new Date()
  today.setHours(11)
  today.setMinutes(30)
  const r = getDateTZ(today)
  expect(r).toEqual('09:30')
})
```

Note: The difference between my location and UK is 2 hours, UK is with 2 hours behind.
The test passed. So running the test alone without running all tests it passes. 
 ISSUE: To run all tests from entire project in my package json i added this task: `"test": "TZ=UTC jest` the test above fails and output this when i do `npm run test`:

```css
Expected: "09:30"
Received: "11:30"
```

So when i run all the tests my test fails because i receive `11:30` instead of `09:30` even if the test works if i run it  separately in the test file. 
 **Question**: Why i get this issue and how to get rid of it?

Comment: have the same issue, maybe you can convert it to timestamp instead (with moment().valueOf()) and then use it

Comment: @Ar26, i don't use moment js. Is there a solution in my case using native code? Or at least what to change, the test pr the code?

Comment: If the code is working ok I think it's better to change the test, you can use native js to get the timestamp new Date(DATE_TO_CHECK).getTime()

Comment: @Ar26, then could you please show how my test should look because i am not sure if i understand?

Comment: You're using `toLocaleTimeString` which will return the string in the timezone of your locale. When you set it to UTC, the value that returns is different. You can use the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` object instead - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat - it's more flexible, and you can explicitly tell each instance what locale it should use. You can write a utility around it for your specific use cases, but honestly it's pretty easy to use out of the box.

Comment: @Derek, do you mean that i should declare explicitly the TZ not only in my function but in the same time in the test? Because i declared one time in my function.

Comment: @Derek, could you help please?